# jQuery .on() is not working for 2 classes

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Here is my code, I want to trigger click event for both pagination classes links. but it is working for 1 class only.

```
<section id="search-result">
        <p class="pagination">
            <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">‹ First</a>
            <a rel="prev" data-ci-pagination-page="10"><</a>
            <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">1</a>
            <a data-ci-pagination-page="10">2</a>
            <strong data-ci-pagination-page="20">3</strong>
            <a href="/10" data-ci-pagination-page="30" rel="next">></a>
            <a href="/550" data-ci-pagination-page="550">Last</a>
        </p>
        <div class="results">
        </div>
        <p class="pagination">
            <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">‹ First</a>
            <a rel="prev" data-ci-pagination-page="10"><</a>
            <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">1</a>
            <a data-ci-pagination-page="10">2</a>
            <strong data-ci-pagination-page="20">3</strong>
            <a href="/10" data-ci-pagination-page="30" rel="next">></a>
            <a href="/550" data-ci-pagination-page="550">Last</a>
        </p>
    </section>
$('.pagination').on( "click",'a', function(e) {
    $(this).css('color','red')
});
```

Comment: It should work. Any errors in console.?

Comment: This code demonstrably works: https://jsfiddle.net/gnvp2oto/  Seems that your debugging is mistaken.

Comment: @ANS yes code is working. but it is not working for same time on both classes

Comment: @David   $(this).css('color','red') try this. it will change color for one link for one pagination class

Comment: @FatimaZohra: It changes the color of the link being clicked.  (Briefly, before the browser navigates to the link target.)  Which is what `this` refers to.  Which is exactly what I'd expect.  What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: to change change both links for both pagination class

Answer (score 1):

I think its working, have a check

```js
$('.pagination').on("click", 'a', function(e) {
  alert('hi')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="search-result">
<p class="pagination">
  <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">‹ First</a>
  <a rel="prev" data-ci-pagination-page="10"></a>
  <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">1</a>
  <a data-ci-pagination-page="10">2</a>
  <strong data-ci-pagination-page="20">3</strong>
  <a href="/10" data-ci-pagination-page="30" rel="next">></a>
  <a href="/550" data-ci-pagination-page="550">Last</a>
</p>
<div class="results">
</div>
<p class="pagination">
  <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">‹ First</a>
  <a rel="prev" data-ci-pagination-page="10"></a>
  <a data-ci-pagination-page="0">1</a>
  <a data-ci-pagination-page="10">2</a>
  <strong data-ci-pagination-page="20">3</strong>
  <a href="/10" data-ci-pagination-page="30" rel="next">></a>
  <a href="/550" data-ci-pagination-page="550">Last</a>
</p>
</section>
```

Comment: try this  $(this).css('color','red'), it will change color for one link for one pagination class

Comment: @FatimaZohra `$('this')` will always target current object. You cant change both the elements using  `$('this')` ;)